# Message Mapper throwing TypeLoadException after updating solution to nServiceBus 5

Tags: xml, serialization, nservicebus

We are upgrading a project from NSB v3 to NSB v5, and having problems with MessageMapper.  Classes that worked fine with NSB 3 are now throwing type loaded exceptions with NSB 5.

The exception is:

```
Method 'DeepCopy' in type 'Benefex.Core.Interfaces.DTO.IUserContext__impl' from assembly 'Benefex.Commands.Operations.Batches__impl, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
```

The stack trace is:

```
at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.TermCreateClass(RuntimeModule module, Int32 tk, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock()
at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateType()
at NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper.CreateTypeFrom(Type t, ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
at NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper.GenerateImplementationFor(Type interfaceType, ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
at NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper.InitType(Type t, ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
at NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper.InitType(Type t, ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder)
at NServiceBus.MessageInterfaces.MessageMapper.Reflection.MessageMapper.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 types)
at NServiceBus.Serializers.XML.Config.MessageTypesInitializer.Run(Configure config)
at NServiceBus.Configure.Initialize()
at NServiceBus.Bus.Create(BusConfiguration configuration)
at Benefex.Core.Processor.ProcessorConfiguration.Customize(BusConfiguration configuration) in c:\TFS\Benefex\Work Streams\SignIn\Benefex.Core.Processor\ProcessorConfiguration.cs:line 33
at Benefex.P1Processor.MessageEndpoint.Customize(BusConfiguration configuration) in c:\TFS\Benefex\Work Streams\SignIn\P1Processor\Server.cs:line 12
at NServiceBus.GenericHost.PerformConfiguration(Action`1 moreConfiguration)
at NServiceBus.GenericHost.Start()
at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.WindowsHost.Start()
at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.Program.<>c__DisplayClasse.<Main>b__6(WindowsHost service)
at Topshelf.Internal.ControllerDelegates`1.StartActionObject(Object obj)
at Topshelf.Internal.IsolatedServiceControllerWrapper`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<set_StartAction>b__1(TService service)
at Topshelf.Internal.ServiceController`1.<.cctor>b__1(ServiceController`1 sc)
at Magnum.StateMachine.LambdaAction`1.Execute(T instance, Event event, Object parameter)
at Magnum.StateMachine.EventActionList`1.Execute(T stateMachine, Event event, Object parameter)   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

The IUserContent interface has an implementation class UserContext that does implement the method stated in the exception.  IUserContext is defined in a different project, and its implementation is in another separate project.  While we will likely be changing these in the future, I would like to get NSB 5 working without changing them now.

We are not using XML Serialization (custom JSON instead), but I have not found any way to override the message mapper even though it seems to be part of the XML serialzation process.

Edit - I've managed to get a small test project to throw the same error:

```
using NServiceBus.Features;
using NServiceBus.Persistence;
using Raven.Client.Document;
using NServiceBus;

namespace ServiceBus
{
    public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint
    {
        public void Customize(BusConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var documentStore = new DocumentStore
            {
                ConnectionStringName = "NServiceBus.Persistence"
            };

            configuration.AssembliesToScan(AllAssemblies.Except("ABCpdf9-32.dll"));

            configuration.EndpointName("testqueue");

            configuration.DisableFeature<AutoSubscribe>();
            configuration.DisableFeature<SecondLevelRetries>();

            configuration.UsePersistence<RavenDBPersistence>()
                         .SetDefaultDocumentStore(documentStore);

            var conventionsBuilder = configuration.Conventions();

            conventionsBuilder.DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null &&
                                                       !t.IsInterface &&
                                                       t.Name.EndsWith("Command"));
            conventionsBuilder.DefiningMessagesAs(t => t.Namespace != null &&
                                                       !t.IsInterface &&
                                                       t.Name.EndsWith("Notification"));

            Bus.Create(configuration);
        }
    }

    public interface IDeepCopy<T>
    {
        T DeepCopy();
    }

    public class TestCommand
    {
        public IUserContext UserContext { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }

    }

    public interface IUserContext : IDeepCopy<IUserContext>
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserContext : IUserContext
    {
        public IUserContext DeepCopy()
        {
            return new UserContext
            {
                Id = Id,
                Description = Description
            };
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific version on NServiceBus you're using?

Comment: We were using 3.3.8, moving to 5.1.2

Comment: would registering your custom serializer get you unstuck http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/how-to-register-a-custom-serializer  ?

Answer (score 0):

When you serialize a message and send it over wire, you are sending serialized data that can be de-serialized on another end. With `DeepClone` method what is sent? I'd say you need to strip that method off your command.

Comment: The deep copy method is not serialized (we are using a custom JSON sterilizer).  It seems that where NSB is trying to be helpful by allowing me to send based on interfaces, that does not respect any custom serialization that has been set (to be honest I don't see any way it could).  However this did work on NSB 3.3.8, and now we are moving to NSB 5.1.2 it doesn't, so I assume something in the MessageMapper has changed.  We are currently looking at removing all the classes that implement methods from interfaces from our messages.

Comment: I should say, that this might fairly be considered a problem we have made for ourselves, as we had domain objects leaked into messages (probably not good), it was just not an expected issue with the upgrade as I had not seen any documentation about it (or detailing this limitation in message classes).

Comment: Agree with you, command should be responsible at most validate its data, but not perform another responsibilities.